Lifting pnpm project dependencies to the workspace root
Consider a monorepo with some "top level" projects and some supporting packages. Suppose a few of the supporting packages depend on a massive 3rd party dependency.
- package.json
- pnpm-workspace.yaml
- environments/
    - client1/
        - package.json
- packages/
    - foo/
        - package.json - depends on @massive-lib
    - bar/
        - package.json - depends on @massive-lib
    - baz/
        - package.json - depends on @massive-lib

Problem
If the types of each supporting package depend on the types of @massive-lib, and each supporting package has its own node_modules folder with its own "copy" of @massive-lib due to pnpm; then tsc must parse @massive-lib N times to compile client1.
client1/
- package.json
- node_modules/
  - .pnpm/
    - foo/
      - node_modules/
        - .pnpm/
          - @massive-lib/ <- 1
    - bar/
      - node_modules/
        - .pnpm/
          - @massive-lib/ <- 2
    - baz/
      - node_modules/
        - .pnpm/
          - @massive-lib/ <- 3

tsc does not seem to know/care that these are all symlinks to the same place on disk.
I have tested and validated this with tsc --extendedDiagnostics --generateTrace trace and npx @typescript/analyze-trace trace; showing increases in lines of definitions parsed, increased memory usage, and additional "Duplicate packages" output for every supporting package used.
There is a duplication of work here that I would like to solve.
Edit
I should note that this is with split-lockfiles=true. Since the lockfile should be an input to the compilation task cache (NX), and we do not want to invalidate all builds any time any project gets a new dependency, we want to split the lockfiles.
Possible Solution
I would like to take advantage of node's module resolution searching upwards. By specifying @massive-lib in the workspace package.json file, and then not installing it in the supporting packages, we may be able to read it just once.
Installing the dependency at the root of the workspace is easy. Getting pnpm to not install it for supporting packages is proving much harder.
Constraints
Our linter has a rule to detect undeclared dependencies. Developers may not import * from X unless X is explicitly called out in their package's package.json file. If at all possible, I would like to keep this linting rule to prevent undocumented dependencies.
pnpm.overrides cannot seem to not install a package when specified in the supporting package. From the workspace root package.json, specifying "foo>@massive-lib": "-", using the dependency selector, also does not work.
I also cannot simply remove the supporting packages from pnpm-workspace.yaml, as that would require "hoisting" all of the supporting package's dependencies, and teaching our build tool a new way to determine where the packages are.

"Hoisting" generally seems to mean what I'm aiming for here - moving a package to higher in the file tree - but in the context of pnpm, it means higher within a single node_modules tree; which makes this extremely difficult to google for.

I suspect there may be a way to hook pnpm's package.json reading step, but I consider adding yet another root configuration file to be an option of last resort.
